# how can i acces to my object info inside array in js

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and I don't know how to accesss the object data inside the array. I would like to print every object name in a `console.log`. Is there any way to do it without using a map?

```
const itemsDisponibles = [
   {  
    nombre: "Guantes de Boxeo",
    id:1,
    deporte: "striking",
    colores: "blanco/negro/rojo",
    precio: 8000,
},
{
    nombre: "Kimono Jiu Jitsu",
    id:2,
    deporte: "grappling",
    colores: "blanco/negro",
    precio: 20000,
},
{
    nombre: "Termina Jiu Jitsu",
    id:3,
    deporte: "grapplig",
    colores: "blanco/negro/azul/amarillo",
    precio: 10000,
},
{
    nombre: "Bolsa de Boxeo",
    id:4,
    deporte: "striking",
    colores: "blanco-rojo/negro",
    precio: 12000,
},
{
    nombre: "Guantes MMA",
    id:5,
    deporte: "striking",
    colores: "negro",
    precio: 7000,
},
{
    nombre: "Protector Bucal",
    id:6,
    deporte: "stricking/grappling",
    colores: "negro, blanco, azul, violeta",
    precio: 4000,
  }
];
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working as expected?  It sounds like you're asking how to loop over an array and how to log a value to the console, both of which are topics covered in introductory tutorials...

Comment: [Loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration), and ["working with objects"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple solutions. Here are some:

```
for(let i = 0; i < itemsDisponibles.length; i++){
   console.log(itemsDisponibles[i].nombre);
}

for(let obj of itemsDisponibles) {
   console.log(obj.nombre);
}

itemsDisponibles.forEach(obj => console.log(obj.nombre));
```

map function is usually used to create a modified version of the original array, since the map function returns a new array once finished.

```
let names = itemsDisponibles.map(obj => obj.nombre);
console.log(names);
```

Comment: `of` not `in` for arrays: `for(let obj of itemsDisponibles)`.

Comment: @Andy Oh yea thx. FIxed it.  for in is for objects.

Comment: map is not used to modify an array, it returns a new one without touching the original one